# Is there a place to find the parameter values used to run a stored procedure?

Tags: testing, sql-server-2012

I have just been asked to test 200+ stored procedures (after a DML change and recompile) to make sure that they work in a database that has no unit testing implemented.

As I don't know what "appropriate" input would be for all of these stored procedures, I was wondering if there's a log of procedures that have been run along with the parameters used to run them.

If not, is there a way of testing a bunch of procedures without knowing what valid inputs for their parameters would be?

Or am I about to learn why systems should incorporate testing from the start of the system?

Thanks

Comment: Suppose you run you procedure without data. How can you verify that it worked correctly?

Comment: Well, you can't run them, let alone know if they worked correctly.  I'll modify the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't able to get the information that I had hoped to get from the database.
So, instead, I created an execution listing of all the stored procedures and functions I could find with their parameters using the following:

```
DECLARE @NAME NVARCHAR(100) =NULL, @SPECIFIC NVARCHAR(100), @PARAMETER NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @LISTING NVARCHAR(MAX) =''

DECLARE PARAM_CURSOR INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR
       SELECT  SPECIFIC_NAME, PARAMETER_NAME
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
       where SPECIFIC_NAME in (
                                select OBJECT_NAME(object_id) name
                                from sys.objects
                                where (OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE 'whatever you''re querying'
                                )
                    )
OPEN PARAM_CURSOR   
FETCH NEXT FROM PARAM_CURSOR INTO @SPECIFIC, @PARAMETER 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
       IF @NAME = @SPECIFIC 
             SET @LISTING = @LISTING + ',' + @PARAMETER
       ELSE 
             BEGIN
             SET @NAME = @SPECIFIC
             SET @LISTING = @LISTING + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+ 'EXEC '+@NAME+' '+@PARAMETER
             END
       IF LEN(@LISTING) > 3000 
             begin
             PRINT @LISTING
             set @listing = ''
             end        
       FETCH NEXT FROM PARAM_CURSOR INTO @SPECIFIC, @PARAMETER 
END
PRINT @LISTING
close PARAM_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE PARAM_CURSOR
```

Then I created a list of all the common parameters, and figured out what appropriate values for each of them would be.
Obviously that wasn't ideal, but since I couldn't find another way, I had to do some things manually.

Hope this helps someone else in the future!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get this information from somewhere like `sys tables` or another place. One thing you can do is to use `SQL Server Profiler` or `Extended Events`. This way you can catch all procedure calls with parameters you need.